# Eclipse: XML syntax coloring for non-XML files

Tags: xml, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, vxml

In my previous (and first) foray into Eclipse, I inherited another Developer's workstation and setup.  Now, I'm trying to setup a new Eclipse instance from scratch, and, in turn, am scratching my head.

How do I go about getting XML-style syntax coloring for files that do not end in .xml (specifically vxml files, in this case)?

Thanks!
IVR Avenger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define which extensions are mapped to which content-types ; this should help Eclipse do what you want.

For that, go to : Window > Preferences > General > Content-types

Then find the "XML" content-type on the right on the screen.

When you click on it, there will be a list of extensions at the bottom of the dialog box.

Click the "Add..." button, and define your extension here in the popup : *.vml

Click OK to close the preferences window...

... And .vml files should now be considered as XML ;-)

Comment: You're welcome ^^ (I had to do the same in PHP, working with Drupal and it's *.module files that contain PHP code... )